# Type name expected

Tags: c++, dos, bgi

"Error C:\BORLANDC\BIN\PIXEL.CPP 6: Type name expected" on trying to define "kolor" string. Editor: Borland C++ on DOS. This program asks about x, y and color of pixel, clears the screen and put pixel on screen. What's wrong?

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <string.h>
int x, y;
string kolor;

void main()
{
    cout << "PIXEL TEST";
    cout << "WPISZ LICZBE X";
    cin >> x;

    cout << "WPISZ LICZBE Y";
    cin >> y;

    cout << "WPISZ KOLOR";
    cin >> COLOR;

    cout << "DZIALAM... TRWA UMIESZCZANIE PIKSELA...";
    int driver = DETECT,mode;
    initgraph(&driver,&mode,"c:\\BORLANDC\\bgi");
        putpixel(x,y,kolor);
    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming your compiler is "standard" enough for my answer to apply. Do consider upgrading your compiler; Turbo C++ doesn't follow any standard particularly well.

Comment: for example https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-express/

Comment: Trying using a char *.   eg  char *kolor;

Comment: @pm100: I'm targeting DOS, not Windows

Comment: Sorry, you are out of luck with this paleo compiler. Why are you using it at all?

Comment: @WatermelonPL: No matter, you can configure MSVC to target DOS.

Comment: I also have a question on why are you targeting DOS to begin with? Is it a learning exercise? Terrible it seems.

Comment: @Bathsheba: But how to target DOS in MSVC?

Answer (score 2):

`string` is in the `std` namespace.

So you need to write `std::string kolor;`, and `#include <string>`.

Ditto with your `cout` and `cin` calls.

An alternative - `using namespace std;` - is possible, but it's poor advice except in short tutorial programs (where it affords clarity), but seldom used in production code due to the resulting *namespace pollution*.

If this *doesn't* fix the compiler errors, then it's really time to upgrade your compiler. The Borland compiler has *never* been a standard C++ compiler, although it did have its uses when it was first released all those years ago.

If you are far too attached to the Borland compiler to migrate, then you can use a 3rd party early version of the C++ Standard Library: STLPort is one such example.

Comment: OP using borland c++, it doesn't even have std and namespaces

Comment: @ArunAS does it support string?

Comment: @pm100 no it does not support string, only `char[]` and `char*`

Answer (score 1):

Well problem is that there is no `string` data type in Borland c++. You will need to use a `char[]` or `char*`

But looking at your implementation, that won't be what you need, because the syntax for `putpixel` is

```
void putpixel(int x, int y, int color);
```

So you need to be passing an integer as the color. Look into the integer values of all the color codes. You can also call it as

```
putpixel(x,y,RED);
putpixel(x,y,BLUE);
```

Some standard color codes have already been defined like this.

So you need to take input in a `char[]`, compare ( hard code ), and then pass on the correct color code

The color codes are

```
0   BLACK
1   BLUE
2   GREEN
3   CYAN
4   RED
5   MAGENTA
6   BROWN
7   LIGHTGRAY
8   DARKGRAY
9   LIGHTBLUE
10  LIGHTGREEN
11  LIGHTCYAN
12  LIGHTRED
13  LIGHTMAGENTA
14  YELLOW
15  WHITE
```

Although it is highly suggested to move on to never versions of c++. If your school forces you to learn it, then okay, but you need to learn the never versions as well, as Borland C++ is too outdated and no one uses it anymore